# parsing value to a variable when clicking a checkmark, access, VBA code

Tags: ms-access, vba

What is the VBA code to parse a value into a different field in the db when a checkbox is clicked?

Example code (that doesn't work):

```
Private Sub Step_1_Click()

If Step_1.Value = True Then
Step1_score.Value = 10
End if

End Sub
```

I removed the "value" and got no code errors but the 10 is not showing up in the Step1_score variable in the db. Any advise on the VBA code to parse a value from a checkmark? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `_AfterUpdate` event to make sure the value of `Step_1` gets changed before the event fires:

```
Private Sub Step_1_AfterUpdate()

If Step_1.Value = True Then
Step1_score.Value = 10
End if

End Sub
```

Comment: it automatically classifies it as Click(). How do I alter the properties to choose AfterUpdate()?

Comment: You can just change the code, or use the property sheet and choose the after update event

Comment: ok, I was able to change it to just the AfterUpdate event but getting an error on line: Step1_score.Value = 10. It just highlights that line, doesn't tell me the issue. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try prefixing both controls with `Me.` as in `If Me.Step_1.Value = True Then
Me.Step1_score.Value = 10
End if`

Comment: getting a compile error: method or data member not found on Step1_score but that variable is in the same table as Step_1 and is spelled correctly. I really appreciate the advise

Comment: It needs to map to a text box. You need to add it to the form. You can hide it, though.